# Map example from github [Python]

Tags: python-3.x

I've been studying this weblink (concerning lambdas, maps, and filters) and it seems to be a bit advanced to me however out of curiosity I would love to know how to solve this specific problem given below. For instance how can you convert a string 'hello' to an integer 5? Keep in mind that they should be in one statement.

https://github.com/stanfordpython/python-labs/blob/master/lab4-fp.md

[For each of the following rows, write a single statement using map that converts the left column into the right column:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRZjK.png)

Comment: Using map requires a function.  Example: `mylist = [1, 2, 3] `
`mymap = map(lambda x: x+5, mylist)`   Output mylist -> `[6,7,8]` (it will increase each number by 5). Note that in the place of lambda we can have a full function (`def...`) lambda is just a one-time use function that in our case takes an input `x` and does `x+5` for each that x.

Comment: No need to apologize at the beginning of the post. It is being reviewed anyway :) Try to keep the question content to a minimum so people could help you with minimum effort.

Comment: @ElvirMuslic Thank you for the reply but still if you take a look at the image which I provided it almost seems impossible to do it.

Comment: @Mr.Nun. Yeah I realized that I made my request a bit complex will look forward to make my questions much simpler in the future.

Comment: okay first case `mylist = ['hello', 'world']` then `print(*map(lambda x:len(x), mylist))` try that

Comment: @ElvirMuslic Oh that is very interesting. Didn't think of it in this way!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will only be a tutorial on **HOW TO** solve these.

First example `['hello', 'world']` and expected output `['5', '5']`

`mylist = ['hello', 'world'] # 5 5 would be the lenght of each word`

```
mymap = map(lambda x: len(x), mylist) 
for i in mymap:
    print(i)
```

> Output: 5 5

## Lambda

Instead of `lambda x: len(x)` we could've defined a function:

```
def itemlenght(x):
    return len(x)
```

---

Then used it in a similar manner.

```
mymap = map(itemlenght, mylist)
print(*mymap)
```

---

## Summary

You'll have a list of items and a function that you'll apply to get the correct results. Applying those is as easy as `map(func, listoriterator)`